# is it posible update row values from tables in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a dataset in Data Factory, and I would like to know if is possible update row values using only data factory activities, without data flow, store procedures, queries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Concepts**:

Datasets:

Datasets represent data structures within the data stores, which simply point to or reference the data you want to use in your activities as inputs or outputs.

Now, a dataset is a named view of data that simply points or references the data you want to use in your activities as inputs and outputs. Datasets identify data within different data stores, such as tables, files, folders, and documents. For example, an Azure Blob dataset specifies the blob container and folder in Blob storage from which the activity should read the data.

Currently, according to my experience, it's impossible to update row values using only data factory activities. Azure Data Factory doesn't support this now.

Fore more details，please reference:

1. [Datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction#datasets)
2. [Datasets and linked services in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services).

For example, when I use Copy Active, Data Factory doesn't provide my any ways to update the rows:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

There is a way to do update (and probably any other SQL statement) from Data Factory, it's a bit tacky though.
The **Loopup** activity, can execute a set of statements in Query mode, ie:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/khILx.png]

**The only condition is to end it with select, otherwise Lookup activity throws error.**

This works for Azure SQL, PostgreSQL, and most likely for any other DB Data Factory can connect to.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible in Azure Data Factory, your Data flow should have an Alter Row stage, and the Sink has a drop-down where you can select the key column for doing updates.

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-alter-row

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Above comment regarding ADF data flow, ADF data flow does not support on-permise sink or source, the sink & source should reside in Azure SQL or Azure Data lake or any other AZURE data services.